# crystal report version error during deployment of project on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

during deployment of my website on windows server 2008 give error like

> "Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner,
>   Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   "

in web config file

i installed iis on server 2008 and  visual studio framework.all pages are working when i disabled all assembly of crystal report.but crystal reports are not working so please help me

Comment: are you using correct version(32 vs 64 bit), did you set correct target framework (2.0, 3.5, 4.0)?

Comment: m using version 64 bit  & framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to download and install the correct runtime engine from this link:
http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you lack a reference? Check this link, it seems to be the same error message as yours. Is that possible?

[Crystal Reports in ASP.NET3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575703/crystal-reports-in-asp-net3-5?rq=1)

If not, could you be more precise about your problem? Thank you very much.